# How to Split /cmd_vel into left and right wheel of 2WD robot?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
Can you please help me writing the equation to split the velocity on left and right wheel of a differential robot from the /cmd_vel?
I want to take smooth turns i.e both wheel should rotate in forward direction but at different speed while taking curves /turns

Equation which I encountered till now simply splits the velocity in which one wheel moves in clockwise
Direction and other anticlockwise while taking turns.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334022/how-to-split-/cmd_vel-into-left-and-right-wheel-of-2wd-robot?/) by [atul0532](https://answers.ros.org/users/46253/atul0532/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-26**:
It sounds like you're actually asking about the kinematics of a differential drive robot.

There are a few Q&As about that already here on ROS Answers. Take a look at #q244540 and the resources linked from that answer for instance.

**Comment by [atul0532](https://answers.ros.org/users/46253/atul0532/) on 2019-09-26**:
@gvdhoorn I have seen the post. But unfortunately most of the link for the useful resources are not opening  expect the YouTube video.
Since I have lack of time can please share me link to a blog or documentation from where I can get a good idea.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn is right, this is a topic with an abundance of documentation in the community and simple geometry.

With that said this is how

```
vel_l = ((msg.linear.x - (msg.angular.z * self.wheel_bias / 2.0)) / self.wheel_radius) * 60/(2*3.14159)
vel_r = ((msg.linear.x + (msg.angular.z * self.wheel_bias / 2.0)) / self.wheel_radius) * 60/(2*3.14159)
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atul0532](https://answers.ros.org/users/46253/atul0532/) on 2019-09-26**:
Thanks @stevemacenski. I am noob in this field. Can you tell me the reason of multiplying the equation by (60/(2*3.14))

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-09-26**:
That's conversion between rad and RPM. You dont need that if you dont need RPM

**Comment by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on 2022-10-08**:
@stevemacenski, for the wheel_bias, does this represent the distance between two wheels?
Thank you very much!